# Python : Pass date list to PostgreSQL query and loop it n number of times

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Hi I am using PostgreSQL 12 and have an INSERT sql statement made up of few CTEs as below:

```
WITH CTE1 as (
select date, count(*) from customers where date = %(date_list)s group by date
),
CTE2 as (
select date, count(*) from customers where account_deleted is NULL and date = %(date_list)s group by date
)
INSERT INTO customers_final (date, customers)
select * from CTE1 
union all
select * from CTE2
```

I now want to use Python to loop through a list of dates for different customer datasets (different snapshots of customers over time) and run the query above multiple times, one run for every customer dataset that corresponds to a different date on my list.

```
Example of list: ('2021-03-21', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-23', etc).
```

The expected result should be one row (one CTE) per date per dataset. As we have 2 CTEs in the example we should be expecting 2 rows per date per dataset.

The below should work for a single dataset. Not sure how to also loop through different tables (customer tables):

```
def insert_data(date_list: list):

sql_query = """WITH CTE1 as (
select date, count(*) from customers where date = %(date_list)s group by date
),
CTE2 as (
select date, count(*) from customers where account_deleted is NULL and date = %(date_list)s group by date
)
INSERT INTO customers_final (date, customers)
select * from CTE1 
union all
select * from CTE2""" (

 for date in date_list:
        if date_list is not None and len(date_list) > 0:
            params = {"date": date}
            cursor.execute(sql_query, {"date": date})

        else:
            log.warning(f'No records found.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    date_list = ['2021-03-29', '2021-03-28', '2021-03-27', '2021-03-26']
    insert_data(date_list)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, are you looking for one calculation for all dates?  Or one row per date?  If the latter, why isn't the date part of the data being inserted?

Comment: Hi Gordon it's the latter, had missed the date part but now added back in. Thank you.

Comment: @ERR why are you duplicating data in second cte ,is there a reason?

Comment: CTE1 and CTE2 are not completely the same - CTE2 has an extra where clause "where account_deleted is NULL" if that makes sense?

Comment: You could to do it in single query, like `... date = any('{2021-03-21,2021-03-22,2021-03-23}'::date[])` (for pure SQL)

Comment: Hi Abelisto I think this would give me a unique result as opposed to one row (one CTE) per date, if that makes sense?

Comment: @ERR Is there any difference in your case between something like `insert into t1 select from t2 where x = 1; insert into t1 select from t2 where x = 2;` and `insert into t1 select from t2 where x in (1,2);` (except inserion order)?

Comment: @Abelisto in my case there is a slight difference because I need to run this script across different datasets that are snapshots of the customers over time. If I did "x in (1,2)" I will not know what is the marginal increment by date 1,2,3 etc across all datasets. Otherwise I could just do a simple query and that would not require recursion / Python...Hope that makes sense?